# Cors issue in Laravel and angular application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have hosted laravel and angular application on two different sub domain

but now getting this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://subdomain1.maindomain.in/api/auth/register' from origin
> 'https://subdomain2.maindomain.in' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
> but only one is allowed.

CORS Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');

return $response;
    }
}
```

> api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors'],'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);    
});
```

> Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        //'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];
}
```

> config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try delete the cors middleware in your route. it tells you that you are using two cors headers.